# 2 libraries of jquery still conflicting even with $.noConflict();

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, shared-libraries, conflict

I cannot understand why is my theme still conflicting with a JS I found online.

My theme is yin yang from (http://onioneyethemes.com/yin-yang/)

And the theme I am trying to run is a quote rotator, I will put the code here since its website is down since yesterday:

```
/*
 * jQuery Quovolver v1.0 - http://sandbox.sebnitu.com/jquery/quovolver
 *
 * By Sebastian Nitu - Copyright 2009 - All rights reserved
 * 
 */

(function($) {
    $.fn.quovolver = function(speed, delay) {

        /* Sets default values */
        if (!speed) speed = 500;
        if (!delay) delay = 6000;

        // If "delay" is less than 4 times the "speed", it will break the effect 
        // If that's the case, make "delay" exactly 4 times "speed"
        var quaSpd = (speed*4);
        if (quaSpd > (delay)) delay = quaSpd;

        // Create the variables needed
        var quote = $(this),
            firstQuo = $(this).filter(':first'),
            lastQuo = $(this).filter(':last'),
            wrapElem = '<div id="quote_wrap"></div>';

        // Wrap the quotes
        $(this).wrapAll(wrapElem);

        // Hide all the quotes, then show the first
        $(this).hide();
        $(firstQuo).show();

        // Set the hight of the wrapper
        $(this).parent().css({height: $(firstQuo).height()});       

        // Where the magic happens
        setInterval(function(){

            // Set required hight and element in variables for animation
            if($(lastQuo).is(':visible')) {
                var nextElem = $(firstQuo);
                var wrapHeight = $(nextElem).height();
            } else {
                var nextElem = $(quote).filter(':visible').next();
                var wrapHeight = $(nextElem).height();
            }

            // Fadeout the quote that is currently visible
            $(quote).filter(':visible').fadeOut(speed);

            // Set the wrapper to the hight of the next element, then fade that element in
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(quote).parent().animate({height: wrapHeight}, speed);
            }, speed);

            if($(lastQuo).is(':visible')) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(firstQuo).fadeIn(speed*2);
                }, speed*2);

            } else {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(nextElem).fadeIn(speed);
                }, speed*2);
            }

        }, delay);

    };
})(jQuery);
```

I am pretty sure the reason why it doesn't work is conflict of the theme js to the backlink to jquery

Removing this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Would make my theme work. And adding that (requirement of the rotator) would disable the effects of my theme.

Here is what I did to try to remove the conflict:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('blockquote').quovolver();

    });
</script>
```

But still no luck. Somebody who can help me to remove the conflict?

Comment: find (or build, it isn't that hard... cycle plugin) a rotator that isn't so out of date.

Comment: But this is exactly what we want. Finding or building is not an option. So why the downvote? :-(

Comment: we need to know what order the jquery versions are being included, where the plugins are being included relative to the jquery core scripts, and where the code for each is located. All of that information is very important to getting the two to work side-by-side.

Comment: $.noConflict() isn't going to be enough to remove the conflict due to the fact that the revolver uses `jQuery` and `$.noConflict()` only fixes `$`, not `jQuery`. Please read the docs.

Comment: Yes as what is stated by the answer. If you visit the theme demo site, you will see the order of how the other libs were loaded (at the footer). Thanks!

Comment: Visiting the website shouldn't be required to understand/answer the question.

Comment: Additionally... did you even attempt to use revolver with the newer version of jQuery? i don't see anything within it that wouldn't work with 1.11.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        // You can then use `$` inside this func,
        // it will not show errors now
        $('blockquote').quovolver();  
    });

$.noConflict(true);
```

Comment: or.. you know... use `$.noConflict` correctly. `var myjq = $.noConflict(true)`

Comment: Thanks. So obviously, you simply replaced $ to work harmoniously with the other lib. That makes sense!

Comment: By fixing it the way in this answer, you are causing EVERYTHING on your website to use 1.3.0 rather than the global version that was included.

Comment: Oh no. we both know the reason why there is conflict is because the theme uses certain version of jquery that conflicts with the jquery link back of the rotator. Merging them under same variable just like above, removing the link back needed by the rotator, poof! I got the the version used by me theme instead of 1.3.0.

Comment: @KevinB Could you explain a bit. ?

Comment: Sure. Consider that this is a theme that may be used by more than just TheWolf here. By doing `jQuery = $`, you are overwriting the original version of jquery with the 1.3.0 version. Now, any plugins that use jquery later will use 1.3.0 instead of the base version. By using $.noConflict(true), you would avoid all possibilities of conflict by completely removing 1.3.0 from the global namespace, while still being able to use it with revolver.

Comment: Oh I got It. What about the second method. ?

Comment: That method will work, but you still want to use $.noConflict(true) after it to return window.jQuery back to the base version.

Comment: Okay, thanks for correction. @TheWolf better use the second method and
`$.noConflict(true) after it` as said by Kevin B.

Comment: @Adeel if you edit your answer and add `$.noConflict(true)` to the second example, the system will allow me to remove my downvote (downvotes are locked in after 10 minutes)